# best software package to numerically solve high order nonlinear ODE boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, math-software

I need to numerically solve a 4th and 5th order nonlinear ODE BVP and I was hoping I could get some advice on the best software package to solve these types of problems. I've used MATLABS bvp4c for the 4th order equation and I'm not too confident in the solutions, I am hoping to try another method. 
Any advice will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about "best", but you could try Maple, which has a variety of solution methods.  Is your problem particularly difficult?  For example, is it stiff, or singular, or does it have narrow boundary layers?  Perhaps you could give us an example of the type of problem you're looking at.

Comment: Could you also quantify or at least qualify how you determine your non-confidence in the BVP solution? Does it change materially when you change the tolerances? Is the ode45 forward solution far away from the bvp4c solution?

Comment: What do your mean by "order"?  The highest order derivative, the highest non-linear term, or higher order methods like RK5(4) and beyond?  That would help.,

Comment: Also, are you asking about s/w packages or "methods"?  This is a big deal as many "packages" will have all the same methods so what's really the point?  MAPLE and Mathematica have pretty good ODE solvers and there is the open source ODEINT.  If you are not confident in your answer I would recommend posting some code and letting us check it.  You can't make a finite solver of a continuous "work" unless you check outputs and use step size control and other features.  MATLAB requires you to check, MAPLE for example uses 1000's of intermediate steps for each step to converge.

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of "stiff solvers" in Matlab like "ode15s" ?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses!                                                                            
I'm working with a boundary value problem so all ode## in matlab are out of question. Correct me if I'm wrong. I could iterate through different initial conditions until I get a solution that fits my "end" boundary condition fairly well, but my initial or "start" boundary conditions are strict, plus I would have to guess for 4 since I'm working with a 4th order equation.

Comment: To be specific, it is a 4th order, non-linear, variable coefficient, homogeneous ODE. And by 4th order, I'm referring to the highest derivative. As far as the solution I got with bvp4c in matlab, the solution did not meet the residue minimum that is default in the function so it gave warnings and a wacky looking solution.

Comment: You should be aware that the problem even in a fixed discretization is a high-dimensional nonlinear system of equations. You need to start close to a solution to hope to converge. If you start far apart from a solution, the search for a solution can become trapped in some "valley" with no way out. That is why it is important to have the initial path at least qualitatively correct.